# Memory to memory MOV - Correct Syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I'm trying to accomplish the following with ASM:

`mov [00A30020], [ebx+50]`

So, I want to `mov` the value of `ebx+50` into 00A30020, but the compiler says it's an invalid statement.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to add 50 to the value in ebx and store that to the memory address 00A30020?

Comment: Before the mov instruction, there's an add instruction `add [ebx+50],edx`. I want the value from [ebx+50], so I'm trying `mov [00A30020], [ebx+50]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *memory* to *memory* move (with `mov`, there is also move string). See [this table](http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/MOV#instructionEncodingsTable).

You could load to a temporary register and then store it:

```
mov   eax, [ebx+50]
mov   [00A30020], eax
```

or to avoid using any extra registers at the cost of being inefficient:

```
push  dword [ebx+50]
pop   dword [00A30020]
```

Comment: A third option would be to use movs, but not very effective.