# why can't I use mov dword[402000],[402010]

Tags: assembly

so in ollydbg, when I wrote this code

mov dword[402000],[402010]

it gave me Constant is out of range error

which I don't know why it is.

I specified how much of data am I gonna use by stating it as "dword"

and [402000], [402010] have exact same size (If I'm right).

so can somebody explain me why does it happen ?

Comment: Because x86 [_MOV_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) doesn't take multiple memory operands

Comment: oh that make sense ty

Comment: Duplicate of [Memory to memory mov correct syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249234/memory-to-memory-mov-correct-syntax) and [Why IA32 does not allow memory to memory mov?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953352/why-ia32-does-not-allow-memory-to-memory-mov). In general, you cannot just make up instructions. You must follow the rules in the manual.